# How to set URL path for overlay/modal in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, overlay

Hi I am trying to make a Meteor web app that uses primarily modals to navigate from one page to another. I have worked with modals in Meteor before, using a package called "Crater Modals", but the problem is I did not configure any URL to it. So if I want a URL link that goes directly to the page with the modal open, I cannot do it, and if I navigate to a certain modal, the URL doesn't change. How can I add those features in Meteor? I have been using Crater Modals, but let me know if your solutions requier use of other modals.

Comment: Have a look at Iron:Router